# Tables are not created when I publish NET-CORE React & DB to Azure

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-sql-database

I created a basic .NET-CORE React & DB (Entity Framework) via the provided template. When publishing the App to Azure, the DB is created without the tables.

I assume something in the configuration is wrong but I couldn’t figured it out.

Any advice please.

Thank you

https://github.com/CJ18874/cj-hello-world
[image]

Comment: are you publishing using using visual studio?

Comment: I can't find it now, but if you were using VS publish, there is a check box to tick if you want to automatically run migrations on publish

Comment: yes I am using Visual Studio